# WPF DataTemplate not throwing exception

Tags: wpf, exception, datatemplate

While designing a new WPF application I noticed exceptions not being thrown during data binding for controls with DataTemplates.  To test I wrote the following simple user control with as little logic as possible.  I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1, VS2008 SP1 running on WIN7.

When the DataContext is set, TestMethod is called and an exception is thrown in the codebehind but the application doesn't break.

Would someone mind explaining what is happening when the DataTemplate is being created?  Specifically I'm interested in where the exception goes.

Below is the XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF2008.DataTemplateQuestion"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TESTKey">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Txt}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Lbl}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="Am I disabled?" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="I am disabled." IsEnabled="False" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="lblTest" Content="{Binding Path=TestMethod}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TESTKey}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Below is the codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPF2008
{
    public partial class DataTemplateQuestion : UserControl
    {
        public DataTemplateQuestion()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                lblTest.DataContext = new TestClass();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // ADDING A BREAKPOINT HERE DOESN'T CATCH THE EXCEPTION
                throw e; 
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestValue TestMethod
        {
            get
            {
                // BREAKPOINT WILL BE HIT WHEN DEBUGGING BUT THE EXCEPTION DISAPPEARS
                throw new Exception("WATCH ME DISAPPEAR");
                return new TestValue { Lbl = "Label", Txt = "Text" };
            }
        }

        public class TestValue
        {
            public string Lbl { get; set; }
            public string Txt { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions thrown by data bindings get translated into trace, which are delivered to the `DataBindingSource` `TraceSource`, which has a source name of "System.Windows.Data".

You can convert these into exceptions by creating a subclass of `TraceListner` that throws an exception on a trace, and add it to the `Listeners` collection of the `TraceSourceSource`.  This can be done either in code or in your `App.config` file.

Here is how you would do it in code:

```
System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(
  new MyTraceListener());
```

See TraceSource and TraceListener documentation and samples for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions get eaten by data bindings, and result in the data binding being disabled (I'm not 100% sure this is the case here, I'm too lazy to put it into VS).

Another possibility is that you may be hitting http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976038 if you are running a 64-bit OS.

Comment: I changed the code to test if the data binding is being disabled but find it to display just w/ no data (see new code).

Am running Win7 x64 so installed the hotfix and enabled it at the system level but resulted in no changed.

Any other thoughts?